# How to select values in for loop?

Tags: c#, selenium

I write program get the proxy.
I only get the IP Address and Port to insert in this DataTable.
Like this:

```
proxy_l {string[9]} string[]
[0] "IP Address"    string
[1] "Port"  string
[2] "Code"  string
[3] "All21134299883128312944344445555808080808180858118812881468888 AllUS AllUnited States Allanonymouselite 
[4] "52.8.219.180 80 US United States anonymous no yes 13 seconds ago"  string
[5] "158.69.88.81 80 US United States anonymous no no 1 minute ago" string
[6] "155.14.140.50 8080 US United States anonymous no yes 1 minute ago" string
[7] "23.244.68.94 80 US United States anonymous no no 1 minute ago" string
[8] "70.43.70.181 80 US United States anonymous no yes 1 minute ago"    string
[9] "165.139.149.169 3128 US United States elite proxy no yes 1 minute ago" string
```

Here my code:

```
var proxy_l = prx.FindElementById("proxylisttable").Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
for (int i = 0; i < proxy_l.Length; i++)
{
    if (proxy_l[i].ToString().ToLower().IndexOf("US") != -1)
    {
        var proxy_lc = proxy_l[i].Split(' ');c[1] + "',0)");
        mysql_db.query("insert into proxy_list(proxy_url,is_ssl) values('" + proxy_lc[0] + ":" + proxy_lc[1] + "',0)");
    }
}
```

### I want my result when insert in database like this:

```
 `IP`                `Port`
```

### `52.8.219.180   80`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, your code is vunerable to sql injection. So I've changed it to use parameterized queries. Secondly, I'm making the assumption that your proxy_list table has columns called 'IP' and 'Port'. This should get you started:

```
string[] proxy_l = prx.FindElementById("proxylisttable").Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

var proxyInfos = proxy_l
    .Where(l => l.Contains(" US "))
    .Select(l => l.Split(' '))
    .Select(tokens => new
    {
        IP = tokens[0],
        Port = tokens[1]
    })
    .ToList();

using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection())
{
    foreach (var proxyInfo in proxyInfos) {
        using (MySqlCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cm.CommandText = "insert into proxy_list(ip, port) values(@ip, @port);";
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", proxyInfo.IP);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@port", proxyInfo.Port);
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```